# Making tree from flat array data

Tags: javascript

suppose our array is like this

```
0: (1) [{…}]
1: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
2: [{…}]
3: (2) [{…}, {…}]
4: (2) [{…}, {…}]
5: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
6: (2) [{…}, {…}]
7: (2) [{…}, {…}]
8: (2) [{…}, {…}]
9: (2) [{…}, {…}]
10: (2) [{…}, {…}]
11: (2) [{…}, {…}]
12: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
13: (2) [{…}, {…}]
14: (2) [{…}, {…}]
15: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
16: [{…}]
```

Here is complete file https://pastebin.com/GSePG9qN . It is large so i truncated it.

So from the above array we can see that
`0:` has 1 children which means 1 is children of 0.
`1:` has 3 children which means 2,3 and 4 are its children.

How do I merge them effectively so i can make it like this

```
{
  data: 0 data
  children: [
   {
     data: 1:data,
     children: {
       {
         data: 2:data,
         children: similar..
       },
       {
         data: 3:data,
         children: similar
       }
     }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried iterating over for loop but the part where we add children to new variable is so confusing.

Thanks

Comment: You have to show us the code you’ve tried already for us to help you.

Comment: and please add data, who can be used for the problem. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: It's not at all clear why `1: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]` means `1`'s children are `2, 3 & 4`. We all speak Javascript here, it will be much clearer if you post actual javascript for your example.

Comment: @MarkMeyer hi its way to store tree like data on array.

Comment: Okay, but still, where do I get 2, 3, 4 out of `1: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]`. Is that what is inside the `{...}`?

Comment: In other words just showing us a bunch of braces and dots is virtually meaningless. Certainly not something anyone can process with code to get the desired results

Comment: The question is very vague with poor documentation . Stackoverflow is not meant to write  prodcution ready code for you .

Comment: Wait I will write all the thing. I thought it may be too more so i didn't wrote it.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I have added pastebin link . I don't wanted to show like 200 lines etc.

Comment: @MarkMeyer regarding solution I tried iterating with 2 loops but it always give me problem while adding nested children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the fancy nested array, I added the children index to each object.

The tree is build by iterating at the first index and all children are taken from the array by using the index for the nested items.

```js
const buildTree = o => Object.assign({}, o, { children: (data[o.children] || []).map(buildTree) })

var data = [
        [{ id: 0 }],
        [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
        [{ id: 4 }],
        [{ id: 5 }, { id: 6 }],
        [{ id: 7 }, { id: 8 }],
        [{ id: 9 }, { id: 10 }, { id: 11 }],
        [{ id: 12 }, { id: 13 }],
        [{ id: 14 }, { id: 15 }],
        [{ id: 16 }, { id: 17 }],
        [{ id: 18 }, { id: 19 }],
        [{ id: 20 }, { id: 21 }],
        [{ id: 22 }, { id: 23 }],
        [{ id: 24 }, { id: 25 }, { id: 26 }],
        [{ id: 27 }, { id: 28 }],
        [{ id: 29 }, { id: 30 }],
        [{ id: 31 }, { id: 32 }, { id: 33 }],
        [{ id: 34 }]
    ],
    result;

data.forEach((i => a => a.forEach(o => o.children = ++i))(0));
result = data[0].map(buildTree);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks the build tree function children part was abit hard .